# using bash variable with quotes, ignores filenames with quotes

Tags: bash, variables

I run a simple bash script that requires double quotes around a multi-part command like so:

```
for i in /data/*; do 
    mycommand "first_directive ; second_directive $i"
done
```

To handle special characters, I put the quotes around the variable so it looks like this:
`"first_directive ; second_directive '$i'"`
which works for the most part, but I found an edge case.

When a filename contains two single quotes, as in `there_are_12''_in_a_foot` it ignores the `''` and just looks for `there_are_12_in_a_foot`

Here is the content of the `data` folder:

```
$ ls /data/
what_do_they_call_a_quarter_pounder
they_use_the_metric_system
there_are_12''_in_a_foot
```

I've tried every combination of quotes I can think of, and searching of course, but I can't find anything that works.

Comment: The value of `variable` has quotes? change the variable names to make the code easy to understand

Comment: I think what you have done is correct and nothing to be changed here. May be the issue is with the `mycommand` script you are invoking. Please provide specific details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use:

```
'${variable//\'/\'\\\'\'}'
```

instead of

```
'$variable'
```

That will escape the single quotes like this:

```
'there_are_12'\'''\''_in_a_foot'
```

*May* because it depends on `my_command` of course.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to escape the `'` with a backslash.

```
there_are_12\'\'_in_a_foot
```

Comment: Yea.. might be a bit hard. But you seem to have a working solution now :)